# Не работает отбор значений по min

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Выделяю минимальные значения каждого периода из столбца `Input`. Это 'min'.
Должно получатся минимальное число, но выходит 0.

Как сделать правильно?

```
from itertools import product
import xlrd

df = pd.read_csv('1111.csv')

def first(s):
    return s.loc[(s!=0).idxmax()] # с изменением на idxmin()] не работает

col = 'Input'

mask = (df[col].ne(0) & df[col].shift(-1).eq(0))    
tmp = df.groupby(mask.shift().fillna(0).cumsum())[col].agg([first, 'last', 'min'])

new_cols = ["<first>", "<last>", "<min>"]
df = df.assign(**dict(product(new_cols, [""])))

df.loc[mask, new_cols] = tmp.iloc[:mask.sum()].values
```

```
Пример данных:
    Input
7   0
8   0
9   0
10  0
11  0
12  0
13  0
14  0
15  0
16  22.65
17  22.65
18  22.66
19  22.65
20  22.65
21  22.65
22  22.66
23  22.65
24  22.65
25  22.65
26  22.64
27  22.64
28  22.65
29  0
30  0
31  0
32  0
```

Что должно быть:

```
    Input   <first> <last>  <min>
7   0           
8   0           
9   0           
10  0           
11  0           
12  0           
13  0           
14  0           
15  0           
16  22.65           
17  22.65           
18  22.66           
19  22.65           
20  22.65           
21  22.65           
22  22.66           
23  22.65           
24  22.65           
25  22.65           
26  22.64           
27  22.64           
28  22.65   22.65   22.65   22.64
29  0           
30  0           
31  0           
32  0           
33  0           
34  0           
35  0           
36  22.64   22.64   22.64   22.64
37  0           
38  0           
39  0           
40  0
```

[Файл данных](https://wdho.ru/hTqJ).
[Пример CSV](https://wdho.ru/9v5w) - в нем уже есть `first`, `last`, `min`, но `min` пустой - т.к. этот код его не вычислил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно написать собственную функцию для нахождения минимума, которая будет игнорировать нулевые значения:

```
def mmin(ser):
    return ser.loc[ser != 0].min()
```

дальше пользуемся практически тем же кодом, что и у вас в вопросе:

```
mask = (df[col].ne(0) & df[col].shift(-1).eq(0))
tmp = df.groupby(mask.shift().fillna(0).cumsum())[col].agg([first, "last", mmin])
# NOTE: -------------------------------------------------------------->    ^^^^

new_cols = ["<first>", "<last>", "<min>"]
df = df.assign(**dict(product(new_cols, [""])))

df.loc[mask, new_cols] = tmp.iloc[:mask.sum()].values
```

---

результат:

```
In [39]: df
Out[39]:
    Input <first> <last>  <min>
7    0.00
8    0.00
9    0.00
10   0.00
11   0.00
12   0.00
13   0.00
14   0.00
15   0.00
16  22.65
17  22.65
18  22.66
19  22.65
20  22.65
21  22.65
22  22.66
23  22.65
24  22.65
25  22.65
26  22.64
27  22.64
28  22.65   22.65  22.65  22.64
29   0.00
30   0.00
31   0.00
32   0.00
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def applyfunc(df):
    funcs = ["first", "last", "min", "max"]
    n = len(df)
    s = n * [""]
    for func in funcs:
        colname = f"<{func}>"
        if func == "first":
            val = df.Input.iloc[0]
        elif func == "last":
            val = df.Input.iloc[-1]
        else:
            val = getattr(df.Input, func)()
        s[n-1] = val if val != 0 else "" 
        df[colname] = s
    return df   

key = df.Input.apply("sign").abs().diff().abs().fillna(0).cumsum()
df.groupby(key).apply(applyfunc)
```

Comment: Программа создает тоже столбец **<max>** — это возможно отменить (или попросить о прибавление других столбцов например **<mean>** или **<std>**)  простым изменением списка `funcs` во второй строке программы.

Comment: @Максим, спасибо вам, я отдал голос для MaxU ;-) Но нужно сказать, что ваш подход к таблицам не «пандасоидным» — смешивать в таблице отдельные значения с суммарными, даже в отдельных столбцах, которые даже содержат пустые строки и числа. Не привыкайте к этому, надо было создать отдельную суммарную таблицу. Желаю много счастья в работе с pandas.

Comment: В последней строке моей программы только выражение, которое создает результат. Jupyter Notebook или IPython его автоматически показывают. Иначе нужно его присвоить какой-то переменной, например и прямо `df`, так: `df = df.groupby(key).apply(applyfunc)`.

Comment: Интересный ответ :)

Comment: @MaxU, спасибо, у вас почти каждый является таким. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ваша проблема в том, что ваша функция

```
def first(s):
    return s.loc[(s!=0).idxmax()] # с изменением на idxmin()] не работает
```

не работает правильно *ни с `.idxmax()`!*

Посмотрите:

- `(s!=0)` — это серия из *логижеских* значений, т. е. `True` / `False`,
- когда в этой серии будут присутствовать *обе* эти значения, то минимальным будет `False` и максимальным будет `True`,
- в вашем случае она начинается с `False`, значит, `(s!=0).idxmax()` будет `0`,
- пусть она будет например `False`, `False`, `True`, `True`, `True`, `False`,
- тогда `(s!=0).idxmax()` будет `2`, другими словами, *индекс первого ненулевого значения серии `s`,* что вы вероятно не хотели.

Comment: Мне надо еще подумать, может быть завтра буду знать.

Comment: @Максим, я написал еще один [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1133236/233990) с полным решением вашей проблемы, с другим подходом, различным от вашего. Добавил тоже столбец **<max>** — его возможно удалить (или прибавить другие столбцы, например **<mean>** или **<std>**)  простым изменением списка `funcs` (вторая строка программы).